# Viewcube in Unity3d like viewcube in navisworkds

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, autodesk-navisworks

I need make viewcube in Unity3d like viewcube in navisworks (http://revitclinic.typepad.com/my_weblog/2010/08/view-cube-compass-and-orient-to-view.html): when rotate cube or click some side of cube - must rotate model around pivot (center model example) (http://prntscr.com/dtp41m)

In Unity3d I made 3d cube in canvas and move its like:

`Vector3 p = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width - offset, Screen.height - offset, z));
transform.position = p;`

where offset is indent from border screen.

On side of cube I made planes with textures contains name of side:
http://prntscr.com/dtokdv

Comment: There is not even a question here. StackOverflow is not a code writing service, consider trying stuff out and post what you tried.